# got stuck with my jquery simple accordian

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build an accordion by myself using jQuery. This is very simple, but I can't get it right.

This is my HTML

```
<div id="three">
  <dt><a href="#">click one</a></dt>
  <dd>content one</dd>
  <dt><a href="#">click two</a></dt>
  <dd>content two</dd>
  <dt><a href="#">click three</a></dt>
  <dd>content three</dd>
</div>
```

This is my script

```
$('dd').hide();
$('a').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().next('dd').toggle('slow', function() {
    });
$(this).parent().siblings('dd').hide();
})
```

It will toggle the `dd` content when a `dt a` is clicked, but I want to close the other opened `dd` as well.

Comment: Instead of toggling the dd you want to show. Maybe you would better hide all dt. then, show `this.next('dd')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to give the element that holds the according a class so that you can easily find the "root" of the accordion:

```
<div id="three" class="accordion">
```

Then you can easily find all `dd` elements inside of it and hide all of them but the one that was clicked:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    var $dd = $(this).parent().next('dd');
    // hide all others
    $(this).closest('.accordion').find('dd').not($dd).hide();
    $dd.toggle('slow');
});
```

In general, if you work more with classes than with elements (i.e. `.accordion-header`, `.accordion-content`, or something like this) and work with "relative" DOM traversal (`.closest`) instead of direct traversal (`$(this).parent()`), you can make your accordion implementation more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Hide on click

```
$('dd').hide();
$('a').on('click', function(){ $(this).parent().next('dd').toggle('slow').siblings('dd').hide('slow');
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VtBn2/)

Answer (score 0):

In `onclick` you just `hide all` before `toggling.`

```
$('dd').hide();

$('a').on('click', function(){
    $('dd').hide();
    $(this).parent().next('dd').toggle('slow', function() {
    });

})
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VtBn2/2/)

Comment: Clicking on an open panel will not close it now.

Answer (score 0):

HI try like this,

```
 $(function() {
$( "#three" ).accordion();
});
```

You can use `accordion` using `Jquery Ui`

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Where does `.accordion` come from? It's not a jQuery method: http://api.jquery.com/?s=accordion.

Comment: That's jQuery UI, not jQuery. The OP doesn't mention he uses jQuery UI, so if your answer depends on it, then you should at least explain this properly in your answer. In any case, it is not a helpful answer IMO, since the OP wants to know how he can achieve the effect with the code he has.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code.

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('dd').stop(true,true).slideUp(); 
    $(this).parent().next('dd').stop(true,true).slideDown();    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JQuery UI Accordion` from [this](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) link. And use it like:

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

On this structure:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>click one</h3>
  <div><p>content one</p></div>
  <h3>click two</h3>
  <div><p>content two</p></div>
  <h3>click three</h3>
  <div><p>content three</p></div>
</div>
```

See example [there](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/nagQQ/).